# Proving $\int_a^b f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ Be an Integrable function on $[a,b]$.

Prove: If for every  $I  ⊆ [a,b]$ We can find $ t ∈ I$ such that $f(t) = 0$, Then:

$\int_a^b f(x) = 0$.

I tried to show the upper darboux sum will be zero, With no results.

Any hints please?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $I$? If it's any subset, then you just take singletons and immediately conclude.

Comment: Btw, I found the duplicate target simply with a Google search for “integrable function has a zero in each interval”